# Why model renders with a blade color with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]

Hi, I imported my model (obj + mtl + texture) but it renders with a blade color.

Normally it should be like this :

[image]

Currently the code of the scene configuration is:

```
loadModel()

    scene.current.background = new THREE.Color( 'transparent' );

    scene.current.add(new THREE.AxesHelper( 5 ));

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, depthWrite: false } ) );
    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.current.add( mesh );

    controls.current.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
    controls.current.dampingFactor = 0.2;
    controls.current.screenSpacePanning = false;
    controls.current.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
    controls.current.maxDistance = 200
    controls.current.minDistance = 20
    controls.current.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 16, 0)

    camera.current.position.set( -3, 17, 8 );
    camera.current.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 15, 0 ));
    controls.current.update();

    scene.current.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );

    const ambilentLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.5)
    scene.current.add(ambilentLight)

    const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff );
    hemiLight.position.set( 0, 500, 30 );
    hemiLight.castShadow = true
    scene.current.add( hemiLight );

    scene.current.add(new THREE.HemisphereLightHelper( hemiLight, 5 ));

    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    dirLight.position.set( -10, 50, 50   );
    dirLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.current.add( dirLight );

    scene.current.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper( dirLight, 5 ));

    renderer.current.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.current.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.current.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.current.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    renderer.current.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
    renderer.current.toneMappingExposure = 1;
    renderer.current.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
    container.current.appendChild(renderer.current.domElement);

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

    animate();
```

I dont know if it's a problem of lighting or another thing.
Anybody know this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with OBJ/MTL and set `WebGLRenderer.outputEncoding` to  `THREE.sRGBEncoding;`, I suspect the issue is caused by an incomplete color space configuration. You can solve this in two way:

1. Do no touch `outputEncoding`.
2. Set the `encoding` property of all color textures to `THREE.sRGBEncoding;`.

Since `OBJLoader` returns an instance of `THREE.Group`, you can update the textures like so:

```js
group.traverse( function( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh === true && object.material.map !== null ) {

        object.material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

    }

} );
```

BTW: You normally use tone mapping only if you apply HDR textures to your scene.

Comment: thank you very much for this information. The problem was, as you said, to use `renderer.current.outputEncoding = true`. Have a nice day